# Can't Assign A String value in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

My codes are to:

- Select a local Mp3 Uri
- Upload it to Firebase
- then retrieve that mp3 metadata such as name, artist, album cover,...
- Upload the album cover to Firebase
- Create a new object in the Firebase Realtime Database including the mp3 and cover download links, the name, and artist.

I have a [Create the String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQSB9.png)

Then inside the mp3 upload onSucess() I retrieve the metadatas and upload the mp3 album cover: [Uploading the album cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j4Cw.png) and assign the downloadLink to the str created above.

Finally create a song object and push it to he Realtime db: [push song object to db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxa4e.png)

but the str is = "". And the result on the db is like this [db result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2oN6.png)

I have checked inside the onSucess() in the 2nd img, the str is = the downloadLink but when moved to the 3rd img it = "" again.

I have tried static, non-static, local variable, etc for the str but no use.

Here is the full code

```
private static String str = "";

private void uploadFile() {
    if (!filename.getText().toString().equals("") && imgView != null) {
        StorageReference mp3ref = mp3StorageRef.child(SongName.getText().toString().trim() + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(Mp3_uri));

        mp3ref.putFile(Mp3_uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(0);
                    }

                }, 500);

                MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getContext(), Mp3_uri);

                String name = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
                String artist = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
                byte[] art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();


                StorageReference cover = coverStorageRef.child("cover_" + name + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                cover.putBytes(art).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!urlTask.isSuccessful()) ;
                        Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                        str =  (downloadUrl.toString());
                    }
                });



                Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!urlTask.isSuccessful()) ;
                Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                Song song = new Song(name, artist, str, downloadUrl.toString());

                String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(song);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                double Progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressBar.setProgress((int) Progress);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

A way to upload 2 files (mp3 and jpg) and retrieve both files download Links.

Comment: I think what happen here. your str="" that called database and save into database, but str initialize after some millisecond of insert database.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 0):

All Firebase operations are asynchronous and the solution is always the same. Any code that needs to process data as a result of an asynchronous operation, should be placed inside the `onSuccess` method or be called from there. So in your case, you have to move all the code from the inner `onSuccess` right inside the outer `onSuccess`.

```
private static String str = "";

private void uploadFile() {
    if (!filename.getText().toString().equals("") && imgView != null) {
        StorageReference mp3ref = mp3StorageRef.child(SongName.getText().toString().trim() + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(Mp3_uri));

        mp3ref.putFile(Mp3_uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(0);
                    }

                }, 500);

                MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getContext(), Mp3_uri);

                String name = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
                String artist = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
                byte[] art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();


                StorageReference cover = coverStorageRef.child("cover_" + name + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                cover.putBytes(art).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!urlTask.isSuccessful()) ;
                        Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                        str =  (downloadUrl.toString());

                        //
                        Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!urlTask.isSuccessful()) ;
                        Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                        Song song = new Song(name, artist, str, downloadUrl.toString());

                        String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                        databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(song);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                double Progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressBar.setProgress((int) Progress);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If you need to use the result of an async operation outside the onComplete, then I recommend you check my answer from the following post:

- [How to return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)

It's true that the answer refers to a read operation, but the exact same rules apply in your case.

Comment: Hey Kaiser. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?